# Xamarin Android Deployment failed because of an internal error

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms

When I try to deploy a `Xamarin Forms Android app` to my Samsung S4 I get the following error message:

> Deployment failed because of an internal error: Package /data/local/tmp/de.tradino_shop.pinkweather-Signed.apk already exists on device.

I looked for the file and wanted to delete it but the file does not exist at the given location. Does anybody have an idea what I could do to resolve this? By the way, the App shows up in Application Manager but can't be deleted or executed. **It just says: not installed.**

Comment: goto settings -> apps -> if you find your app there click it and then choose uninstall for all users this will solve your problem.

Comment: Unfortunately not, I tried that already, the app keeps showing up in the list, stilll marked as not installed.

Comment: I was having the same issue above work around solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and **I solved it** by using the command prompt.

In the command prompt go to the file where adb exist in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools`) and also you must put the `de.tradino_shop.pinkweather-Signed.apk` file in that folder (you will find it in the debug file of your project) then just in the command prompt execute this line: `adb install -r de.tradino_shop.pinkweather-Signed.apk`

After installation finish just clean your project and debug again. Your android phone must be connected to your PC and is on USB debugging mode.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try to go to Settings -> Apps -> All Apps. The path may be different but you need to check the list of all the installed apps and see if your app is in the list. if it is in the the list than uninstall it for all the users.